# Create array of objects from 2D array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I have a 2-D list from a server URL which has a format of

```
[["John",5,7,"something1"],
["David",4,2,"something2"],etc]
```

Is there a fast way to parse this list to a proper JSON format with assigned key pairs as follows?

```
[{name:"John", 
numbercolumn1:5,
numbercolumn2:7,
description:"something1"},
{},{}]
```

Comment: this `"John,5,7,"something1"...17 items in total` is invalid string notation

Comment: Make a mapping object, like `{"0": "name", "1": "numbercolumn1", "2": "numbercolumn2", "3":"description" ... }` and then iterate over your outer array, and your inner array, mapping the numbered indexes to the new field names. `for ( var i = 0, l = innerArray.length; i < l; i++) { newObj[mappingArray['' + i]] = innerArray[i]; }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If these are all your properties you can use [`Array#map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) like this:

```
var data = arr.map(function(a) {
  return {
    name: a[0],
    columnNumber1: a[1],
    columnNumber2: a[2],
    description: a[3]
  };
});
```

**Demo:**

```js
var arr = [
  ["John", 5, 7, "something1"],
  ["David", 4, 2, "something2"]
];

var data = arr.map(function(a) {
  return {
    name: a[0],
    columnNumber1: a[1],
    columnNumber2: a[2],
    description: a[3]
  };
});

console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 1):

- You can create an array with the name of the property of the object first.
- After that you can use  [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to iterate on your list a generate the new list of object.
- Iterate on the property name list to generate the object dynamicaly.

```js
const bigList = [
  ['John', 1, 2],
  ['Doe', 5, 6]
];

const propertyNames = ['name', 'col1', 'col2'];

const newList = bigList.map( item => {
  const newItem = {};
  propertyNames.forEach( (propertyName, index) => {
    newItem[propertyName] = item[index];
  });
  
  return newItem;
});

console.log(newList)
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let data = [["John",5,7,"something1"],
            ["David",4,2,"something2"]];
            
let newData = data.map(d => (
    {name: d[0], numbercolumn1: d[1], numbercolumn2: d[2], description: d[3]}
)) 

console.log(newData)
```

Or without es6 arrow functions:

```js
var data = [["John",5,7,"something1"],
            ["David",4,2,"something2"]];

var newData = data.map(function(d) {
  return {
    name: d[0], numbercolumn1: d[1], numbercolumn2: d[2], description: d[3]
  }
})

console.log(newData)
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

With ES6 you could use a [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) and [short hand properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) for the object.

```js
var data = [["John", 5, 7, "something1"], ["David", 4, 2, "something2"]],
    result = data.map(([name, numbercolumn1, numbercolumn2, description]) => ({ name, numbercolumn1, numbercolumn2, description }));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```